# Doctrine 2.5.14 EntityManager - No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, entitymanager

I can't get through setting up phase of **Entity Manager** on official Doctrine [website](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) tutorial:

I keep geting **No Metadata Classes to process** in the part *Starting with the Product Entity*, where I should in put this code to terminal:

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
```

Here is [link](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2-orm-tutorial) for the repository on github:

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was basically with disabled PHP (7.2). I don't know how this happened. After enabling everything is working fine.